# How to make generic lambda by MakeGenericType

Tags: c#, linq, expression

below is my code fragment

```
        List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        Func<int, bool> f = c => c > 3;
        var result = list.Where(f);
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToList());

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int),"c");
        var constant = Expression.Constant(3);
        var body = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(param, constant);
        var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType( typeof(int), typeof(bool));
        var funcDelegate = Expression.Lambda(funcType, body, param);
        result = list.Where(funcDelegate);

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToList());

        Console.ReadLine();
```

System told me `result = list.Where(funcDelegate);` is wrong, can't convert `"System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression" to "System.Func<int,int,bool>"`

I think I must make mistake at using MakeGenericType method, how can I build the right generic lambda expression by MakeGenericType?

thanks!

Comment: `Expression.Lambda(funcType, body, param)` -> `(Func<int, bool>)Expression.Lambda(funcType, body, param).Compile()`

Comment: @PetSerAl you should put that as an answer, never realized that we can cast around funcs! Is it possible to use the Expression.Lambda<> overload?

Comment: You do not seem to need the MakeGenericType here at all. Why do you insist on using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var funcDelegate = Expression.Lambda<Func<int,bool>>(body, param).Compile();
```

instead of

```
var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType( typeof(int), typeof(bool));
var funcDelegate = Expression.Lambda(funcType, body, param);
```

This way, you won't need to cast the delegate.

(Don't forget the `Compile()` part)